# How to give away a method without giving source?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing for a company and they asked me to write a Java class or something that makes a call with a single click, so it triggers an action where opens a connection to their servers, registers, makes a SIP call and then hangups. But I don't want to give away my source code. I'd like to give them just the method so they do their own application and just have to call the action like

```
<Button android:text="@string/doCall />
```

and import that method in their Java class.

```
public void doCall(View view) { 
  //Code supposed to be hidden
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to jar your classes and share, also provide useful documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Answer (score 2):

You can give the company an interface with the methods you want them to have access to.

Your class will implement that interface, providing the funcionality they need.

Comment: My class or their class?

Comment: Your class would implement that interface, so they can invoke the methods throught the interface, with your class being the one that has the actual code that does thing.

Comment: If I implement that interface "inter" in my class "classy", and then I give them "inter", how would they be able to use classy if I didn't give it to them?

Comment: They can mock to the interface while they are developing by using traditional mocking libraries such as [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)